# How do get multiple value from text file using (Regex) in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm new to Regex. I'm trying to scan few text file and get some field name based on Tag Field and Action. I'm using Powershell and regex = **?smi)\b(field|Action)[^)]+** to get the full Field and action String. Once i get the string now to get the value from field and action string i call **(?<=;).*** However it fails (wrong value) on line **Field("Waiting Period (H)"; "Waiting Period (Hrs.)") {  }** . Please note the Value can be in Quote or no Quote however it will always end with this **)** the problem is some field name can have e.g **(Hrs.)")**

```
{
    group("Default")
    {
       Field("Postal Code"; **Postal**)
        {
         ToolTip = 'Enter Postal Code ';
         trigger OnValidate()
         begin
          If ("Postal Code" <> xRec."Postal Code.") then
            function()
           END;
         }
        field ("Cels or Fahr"; **"Celsius or Fahrenheit"**) {
             ToolTip = 'Enter temperature ';
          }
        Field("Waiting Period (H)"; **"Waiting Period (Hrs.)"**) {  }
        Field ( Latitude; **Latitude**)  
         {
            ToolTip = 'Enter Latitude';
            trigger OnValidate()                   
          }
    }
}  
action(**"Restore to Default"**)
  {
  ToolTip = 'Enter Latitude';
}
```

I'm looking for output for tag "Field Or Action" to return these values below
Postal
"Celsius or Fahrenheit"
"Waiting Period (Hrs.)"
Latitude
"Restore to Default"

So, If i use https://regex101.com/ on the same text **(?<=;).***  the text is **"Waiting Period (Hrs.)") {  }** is wrong **"Waiting Period (Hrs.)") {  }** . Any help or advice will be helpful.

Comment: Maybe regex `(?smi)\b(field|Action)[^{]+` ( note `[^{]+` instead of `[^)]+`).

Answer (score 0):

First get the group

```
group("") {
  field(...) {}
}
```

by

```
$mainText -match '(?smi)\{(?<groupText>\s*?group\(".*"\)\s*?\{\s*?(?:\s*?Field\s*?\((?:\s*?"*?.*?(?:\(.*?\))*?.*?"*?)?;\s*?(?:\*\*"?.*?(?:\(.*?\))*?.*?"?\*\*)?\)\s*?\{.*?\}\s*?)*?\s*?\}\s*?)\}\s*?'
```

and get the groupText capture $groupText = $Matches["groupText"].

```
$fieldMatches = $groupText | select-string -Pattern '(?smi)(?:\s*?Field\s*?\((?<fieldName1>\s*?"*?.*?(?:\(.*?\))*?.*?"*?)?;\s*?(?<fieldName2>\*\*"?.*?(?:\(.*?\))*?.*?"?\*\*)?\)\s*?\{.*?\}\s*?)+?' -AllMatches

$fieldMatches.Matches | %{ $_.Groups["fieldName1"].Value + ' <===> '+ $_.Groups["fieldName2"].Value }
```

The point here is to use lazy matching with *?. And we use a separate match because when there is a repeated capturing groups in a pattern only the last capture matched.

You could similarly match the `action` group separately.